# How Do I Get Rid of the Progress Indicator for RemoteInput Notifications on Android N?

Tags: android, android-7.0-nougat

I used `RemoteInput` to allow the user to enter some text as part of a `Notification` on N Developer Preview 1. It worked, but when the user pressed the "send" button, an indefinite progress indicator appeared, and it never goes away:

[image: RemoteInput Notification on Android]

Is this supposed to happen? How do I get rid of it?

Answer (score 3):

> Is this supposed to happen?

Apparently, yes.

> How do I get rid of it?

Update the `Notification`. That could:

- Add back in the `RemoteInput` to accept new input, or
- Not add back in the `RemoteInput`, but perhaps update other aspects of the `Notification` to indicate that you have received and processed the input

Or, if appropriate, `cancel()` the `Notification`.

[This sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/v7.2/Notifications/RemoteInput) demonstrates the use of `RemoteInput` with the N Developer Preview.

Comment: *Apparently, yes.* not that I don't believe your word for it, but what is this conclusion based on?

Comment: @TimCastelijns: Because [buried in the sample code for this feature](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-MessagingService/blob/77ef7e6f82e490e46664229f0df39378cdff30c0/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/messagingservice/MessageReplyReceiver.java#L49-L58) is the comment `// Update the notification to stop the progress spinner.`. This suggests that the progress spinner is expected behavior. Presumably, the idea is that you don't update the `Notification` until you have consumed the input, which may take a few moments (e.g., send to a server, get an ack).

Comment: @TimCastelijns: You might want to keep tabs on [this issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=203796), where I ask them to clarify the documentation on this point.